# How do I prevent Teams web links from launching desktop app?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm on multiple Teams organizations and I keep the desktop app signed into my primary.  When I get e-mails of messages in the other groups I like to open them in the web browser instead of having my app switch Teams organizations.  Right now when I click the e-mailed link I get a browser tab with buttons for open in app or open in web, HOWEVER, the Teams app is automatically popping up trying to switch even though I've not yet made a selection.  I can cancel the Teams app and then select web browser.  It would be nice if I could get the local Teams app to not prematurely popup at all though.

Comment: If the Teams app is already signed in, I think that will take precedence so you will have to cancel the app as you are doing and go to the browser.

Comment: Which desktop operating system?

Comment: @M.Justin Windows 10

Comment: Did you ever found out how to prevent this behaviour, @BrianKnoblauch?

Comment: @SeanFeldman No, ended up leaving that employer before resolving the issue and at my current employer I only need one Teams organization.  :)

Answer (score 1):

When the launcher page opens, it loads an iframe with a `ms-teams:/` url. The browser then tries to handle this custom uri scheme. It may prompt the user beforehand. Normally it just invokes the default OS handler for that uri scheme. On Windows, that would be `HKLM or HKCU\Software\Classes\ms-teams\shell\open\command\(Default)`

In Edge, you get prompted every time it tries to handle the url. There is a checkbox to stop asking and always use the handler. This is saved into `Settings -> Cookies and site permissions -> All permissions -> Application links`. But it doesn't let you permanently decline. To do that, you'd have to remove the OS handler itself. If no handler exists, opening silently fails.

In Chrome, same deal, but there seems to be no UI to remove the permanently accepted choice. You have to dig through the user `Preferences` json file for `protocol_handler`.

In Firefox, an entry is created in `Settings -> General -> Applications` on first use. It defaults to using the OS handler, and you can flip it to 'Always ask' or enter a custom executable path. Strangely, there is no 'Do nothing' option. Even more strangely, choosing 'Always ask' reverts to the OS handler and it doesn't actually ask you. To undo the saved checkbox, you need to click the 'this site has additional permissions' button on the url bar. And finally, invoking the default OS handler doesn't seem to work at all.

So. Presumably you're using Edge or Chrome, since Teams won't load in Firefox. Not at the moment, anyway. Removing the OS handler might or might not work, because it is likely the Teams app will regenerate it either on every startup or on every autoupdate. So the only option left is to delete the saved prompt confirmation from the browser, and then get used to swatting the prompt away every single time.